# Does Task.RunSynchronously() work "recursively"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

If I call `RunSynchronously()` on a `Task` in C#, will this lead to asynchronous calls further down the rabbit hole to be run synchronously as well?

Let's say I have a method named `UpdateAsync()`.  Inside this method another asynchronous call is made to `DoSomethingAsync()` and inside this again we find `DoSomethingElseAsync()`, will calling `RunSynchronously()` on 'UpdateAsync()' lead to `RunSynchronously()` also indirectly being called on `DoSomethingAsync()`?

**The reason for my question:**
I have a situation where I "need" to call an asynchronous method (`UpdateAsync()`) inside a `catch`-block and wonder if calling this with `RunSynchronously()` is safe.  The documentation is quite clear on the fact that you can't `await` inside a `catch`-block.  (Strictly speaking I could use a boolean inside the `catch`-block and call `UpdateAsync()` after the try-catch, but that feels rather dirty).  Sorry about the dual question, but as you probably understand I don't quite know how to phrase it and do not have a really good understanding of this field.

(**Edit:**
I don't know how to find out if a method was called asynchronously.  How would you write a unit test for this?  Is it possible to log it somehow?)

Comment: If you're using `async/await` and calling an `async` method you most probably don't want to block by calling `RunSynchronously()` anyway - so I would go with the bool flag option.

Comment: @NicholasButler It just felt like a hack to use a bool flag like that, but in a way it does feels safer to call an asynchronous method asynchronously.  This happens only one place in our application now anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I "need" to call an asynchronous method and wonder if calling this with `RunSynchronously()` is safe

There are two kinds of `Task`s: code-based* `Tasks` (you can create those by using the `Task` constructor or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`) and promise-style `Task`s (you can create them manually by using `TaskCompletionSource` or by writing an `async` method).

And the only `Task`s that you can start by calling `Start()` or `RunSynchronously()` are *unstarted code-based `Task`s*. Since async methods return promise-style `Task`s (or possibly already started code-based `Task`s), calling `RunSynchronously()` on them is not valid and will result in an exception.

So, to actually answer your question: what you're asking isn't possible, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether it's safe.

---

* This is not an official name, I don't know if there is one.

Comment: +1  Thanks.  This is complex stuff.  I'm going to go for the bool flag solution.

Comment: @svick, the Task or Task<TResult> returned by async methods is **not** self-starting, so they can be obtained in non-running state using the Task or Task<> constructors. I may be confused myself, but I saw some validity and tried to "model" it on my lunch break - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to predict without code how it will execute nested async methods.

You can log on each async method Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId property and compare id with other thread IDs that you have. When they vary, then your async methods are in multithreaded executtion

Or try to use Concurrency Visualizer from Visual Studio, Analyze menu. With Task class instances and even with C#5 async syntax there is no way to get to know that you are executing in parallel or another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on logging the thread id, I will try that.  About it being hard to predict, does that mean that there is nothing inheritly in `RunSynchronously()` that guarantees what happens further down in code will run synchronously?

Comment: Avout RunSynchronously I haven't found any garantee how nested async methods will be executed. Definitly I can say that RunSynchronously garantee that current async method or task will be executed in the same thread, from where it was called.

Answer (score -1):

I think I'll be contradicting @svick's answer, but I feel the OP question is valid, because an async method's "promised" (to use Svick's terminology) Task can be obtained, but not started, thus allowing to do `Task.RunSynchronously()`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        //obtain a Task that's not started
        var t = new Task<int>((ob) => GetIntAsync((string)ob).Result, someString);
        ...
    }

    static async Task<int> GetIntAsync(string callerThreadId)
    {
       ...
```

Having said that, the answer is: No, the `RunSynchronously()` affects the task you run this on. If the call chain later contains more async calls, they run asynchronously.

I have a little console app that is modeling this, is someone is interested in seeing it, but the concept is pretty simple to reproduce - just chain enough asynchronous calls and toggle between running the earliest one synchronously and asynchronously to see the different behavior.

Comment: How exactly would you get a `Task` from an `async` method that can be `Start()`ed? Maybe you're confused by the fact that the `State` of a promise `Task` is `WaitingForActivation` until it's completed.

Comment: made an edit showing the code. You indicated on the other thread that it's not the same task - and you're probably right - it crossed my mind, but for the intents and purposes of OP question, it is equivalent, so I put that thought behind.

Comment: @G.Stoynev This isn't getting the `Task` of an `async` method in an unstarted state.  This is creating a new task, in an unstarted state that, when started, calls an `async` method.  That is different from getting an unstarted `Task` directly from an async method.

Comment: I thought that too, but that's how you accomplish what the original question is.

Comment: @G.Stoynev Well, you accomplish using `RunSynchronously()` in some way, but it's not in any way useful. Basically, what you're suggesting is just a complicated way to do the same thing as directly calling `GetIntAsync()` does.

Comment: @Svick, I tested that already but `RunSynchronously()' gives me a different behavior than simply `GetIntAsync()' - should I post in another question for you to explain?

Comment: @G.Stoynev Sure, if you want.