# Multiple Async Tasks

Tags: c#, async-await

I have two async mehotds that not directly related to one another (they do both write out though).. and i don't want either to block the efficiency of the other..

If i place one of the activities in a set of tasks like this:

```
var list = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in things)
{
    list.Add(My.MethodAsync(t)); // method returns Task
}

await Task.WhenAll(t);
```

I know that it will not block, and potentially run in parallel..

If i another async method though though:

```
var list = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in things)
{
    list.Add(My.MethodAsync(t)); // method returns Task
}

foreach (var t in things)
{
    await My.OtherAsync(t)); // method returns Task
}

await Task.WhenAll(t);
```

The Task.WhenAll() needs to wait for the second foreach to complete...

Therefore, is something like this possible / recommend?

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in things)
{
    allTasks.Add(My.MethodAsync(t)); // method returns Task
    allTasks.Add(My.OtherAsync(t)); // method returns Task
}

await Task.WhenAll(t);
```

Having typed this out, even though the tasks themselves are independent, it would be nice i guess if an error was raised if both do not output.. hmm

question still stands though ;)

Comment: "The Task.WhenAll() needs to wait for the blocking foreach to complete...", not true. The tasks will be running at the same time

Comment: oh really? i thought the Task.WhenAll(t) would not have kicked off yet, and freed up the main thread? And it couldn't due to the second foreach preventing it..

Comment: If `My.MethodAsync(t)` returns a Task, it is already initiated. `WhenAll` will just asynchronously wait for them to complete, if they haven't already

Comment: I would take a look at this one reguarding the exceptions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete

Comment: `Parallel.Invoke` runs CPU-bound actions in parallel. `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WaitAll` wait for all tasks to complete. You still need to start them before though. Provided that `MethodAsync` and `OtherAsync` returned started tasks, your second example is fine.

Comment: yeah they return tasks... i have updated the original q to show ;)

Comment: @m1nkeh Returning a task is different than returning an un-started task. Without seeing your implementation, I couldn't tell you which you're doing but if you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066349/how-to-construct-a-task-without-starting-it), you'll find some help in that regard

Comment: @Woody1193 i am not explicitly trying to async an unstarted task.. so would assume it's started, lets' just assume they are both writing to the file system...

Comment: @m1nkeh Then you should be fine with the syntax you've provided

Comment: out of interest it if was unstarted (which to be honest i have not heard of) how would it get started?

Comment: @m1nkeh You'd call `task.Start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var t in things)
{
    allTasks.Add(My.MethodAsync(t); // method returns Task
    allTasks.Add(My.OtherAsync(t); // method returns Task
}

await Task.WhenAll(t).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will work just fine. As was pointed out in the comments, if your methods return a `Task` that was started already (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066349/how-to-construct-a-task-without-starting-it)), then all `Task.WhenAll` will do is wait asynchronously for the tasks to complete. These tasks may run in parallel if their run-time is long enough that you can start one before the previous finishes. Note that I added `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your code. Technically, it doesn't actually change what your code is doing as `await` is done with false as the default but it does clarify your intent so I prefer it when I write asynchronous method calls.

Comment: great, well this is what i have done in that case.. many thanks!